# <tr> does not take the height of descendent <span>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-design-lite

This `<tr>` is not taking the height of the descendant `<span>` and some of text overflows into the next row. How can I make the row expand to include both the text and caption?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.green-red.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<table class="mdl-data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cel--non-numeric">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">
            <p class="mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-left">Barack H. Obama</p>
            <p class="mdl-typography--caption mdl-typography--text-left">Democratic</p>
          </span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Current Table:
[image: Current Table]

Desired Table:
[image: Desired Table]

Comment: Is it possible to edit in a complete working example? It's hard to see what you mean without the actual generated/rendered HTML/CSS code. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block` to the span's style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the class `.mdl_checkbox` has a fixed height of 24px (material.indigo-pink.min.css). That class is applied to the `<label>` element. Overriding that style seemed to help.

But I'm not sure how that will affect other elements. Maybe "Material Design Lite" provides for a more integrated solution, rather than just overriding existing styles.

```css
label.mdl-checkbox {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script defer src="//code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<table class="mdl-data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cel--non-numeric">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">
            <p class="mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-left">Barack H. Obama</p>
            <p class="mdl-typography--caption mdl-typography--text-left">Democratic</p>
          </span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

<label>, <span> elements are inline property. So they can't have block property like <p>. 
Please look <label> spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL), and <span> spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-SPAN)

You need to fix elements first, then give padding or height in <span> then give 'display:inline-block' in <span>

```css
label{
  display:block;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.mdl-checkbox__label{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.mdl-typography--body-1{
  display:block;
  padding:0 0 20px;
}
.mdl-typography--caption{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="mdl-data-table" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cel--non-numeric">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">
            <span class="mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-left" >
              Barack H. Obama
            </span>
            <span class="mdl-typography--caption mdl-typography--text-left" >
              Democratic
            </span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add `overflow:hidden` to the `<tr>`, to hide overflowing content,  and if you need to store content inside the one row, try this:

```
label {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

label .mdl-checkbox__input {
   flex-basis: 20%;
}

label .mdl-checkbox__label {
   flex-basis: 80%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis; //will cut the word with ..., if it too long
   line-height: //your value
}
```